# Skipping registering GPU devices"...message in JupyterLab v 3.6.3

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, rtx

**Issue type**
Support

**Have you reproduced the bug with TensorFlow Nightly?**
Yes

**Source**
source

**TensorFlow version**
v1.12.1-106195-g9060e62bf4e 2.17.0-dev20240219

**Custom code**
No

**OS platform and distribution**
Linux Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Python version
**Python 3.11.5**

**CUDA/cuDNN version**
12.2 / I don't know cuDNN version

**GPU model and memory**
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Ti 12282MiB

Current behavior?
While working in Jupyter Notebook throught Anaconda, when importing tensorflow I get this error. I spent a lot of money to be able to use GPU in Data Science works and I'm unable to use it at all...not sure if enviroment is OK...

Driver is:
[Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAi4F.png)

GPU model:
[GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyAfU.png)

**Standalone code to reproduce the issue**

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    print("Name:", gpu.name, "  Type:", gpu.device_type)
```

**Relevant log output**

```
2024-02-19 20:35:30.820121: I external/local_tsl/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:31] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-02-19 20:35:30.851745: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-02-19 20:35:30.851772: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-02-19 20:35:30.852727: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-02-19 20:35:30.857979: I external/local_tsl/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:31] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-02-19 20:35:30.858297: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-02-19 20:35:31.682954: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-02-19 20:35:32.799765: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-02-19 20:35:32.800463: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2256] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

Trying to import Tensor Flow and use the GPU.